# Multiple monitors scaling

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a Lenovo Y50-70 with a UHD 4K 3840x2160 15.6" monitor and I also have an external old Samsung 17" monitor with a resolution of 1280x1024 (5:4). I use Ubuntu 19.10 and I have a serious problem regarding the use of these 2 screens. I read the answers of some topics regarding this problem but I still cannot fix one final problem. I use the following `xrandr` commands:

For external:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --scale 2x2 --mode 1280x1024 --fb 6400x2160 --pos 0x0
```

(The Samsung monitor is in the left of the laptop so this is why I use `--pos 0x0` and why I also did 3840+(2*1280)).

For laptop:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --scale 1x1 --pos 2560x0
```

The problem that I encounter is that in the external Samsung display, it is shown only 1/4 of the screen and the icons remain in the same size. How do I solve this?

The outpur of xrandr without any parameters when I connect the second screen is:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5120 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected primary 3840x2160+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     48.00*+
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1-1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02 +  75.02* 
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: Remove the mode on the HDMI you have value for laptop.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Sorry I was on phone with limited functionality. I mean remove this: `--mode 1280x1024` which changes your 3840x2160 4K TV into a 1280x1024 size which is 1/4 and which is what you are seeing now. Also I'm not sure what the `--fb 6400x2160` is supposed to do so maybe that has to be removed as well?

Comment: I think that you didn't understand what I wrote. So let me explain. the `--mode 1280x1024` is for the external display not for the laptop. As I said the 1/4 is in the external display. Moreover the --fb is for the framebuffer I saw it on another post that I cannot really find right now\

Comment: Can you run `xrandr` (with no parameters) and post the results into your question?

Comment: Can you see something that I am missing?

Comment: Have you made it work without scaling first?

Comment: Yes it runs without scaling, the problem is that the external display has too big icons,letters etc.